# Selenium + Python : I cannot access element in iframe after using driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_id)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe, hidden

[image]

I am using python 3 and selenium in order to do some webscraping.
I usually do not have any problem but this time, I have to access elements in an iframe.

I have been reading around and decided to follow the advises and switch frame and then, look for elements.

So here I switch frame :

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@id, 'ext-gen')]")
iframe_id = str(iframe.get_attribute('id'))

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_id)
```

However, I cannot get the elements in this frame.

[image: [Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElaMS.png)]

```
input_project = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id, "b_s4_l1s4_ctl00_project_i")]')
```

Error stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 input_project = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id, "b_s4_l1s4_ctl00_project_i")]')

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:831 in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:440 in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:245 in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[contains(@id, "b_s4_l1s4_ctl00_project_i")]
```

Comment: not sure if that's a typo in your question or you are actually doing it, but you are looking for an input element using an iframe tag. (`input_project = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[contains(@id, "b_s4_l1s4_ctl00_project_i")]'`)

Comment: @LevanGoderdzishvili, thanks for pointing this out.
I modified my initial post.
However this does not solve the problem.
DO you have any idea what I am doing wrong here ? Thanks!

Comment: it's hard to identify the problem without the HTML. Is this a public website? Provide a link or do the `pastebin` with HTML content

Comment: First off, try `driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)`.

Also, try using waits https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html because the iframe or the element may not be yet loaded in DOM by the time your methods execute

Comment: @LevanGoderdzishvili,
Thanks a lot for your help ! 
looking closely at the html, I discovered that inside the iframe was another frame.
Switching to this second frame made the elements visible! :) 
Thanks again for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are doing this

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@id, 'ext-gen')]")
iframe_id = str(iframe.get_attribute('id')) <<< why?

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_id)
```

You already have the IFRAME element in `iframe`, just use that when switching frames. Also, add a wait to make sure that the frame is ready.

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@id, 'ext-gen')]")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(iframe))
```

Comment: `iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@id, 'ext-gen')]")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(iframe))`

gives me :

`Out[57]: True`

so I think I switched to this iframe.
However, I still cannot access the elements in this iframe

Comment: Can you post a link to the page? I'm guessing that we're either switching into the wrong IFRAME or there could be another IFRAME or shadow-root to switch into but I can't tell without seeing the page or more info.

Comment: I found what I missed! A frame was inside the iframe. So I needed to switch twice

`iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@id, 'ext-gen')]")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(iframe))

frame2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//frame[contains(@id, 'contentContainerFrame')]")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(frame2))

project = driver.find_element(By.ID, "b_s4_l1s4_ctl00_project_i")
project.send_keys("999333")`

Comment: You can delete the second instance of `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`. Once the `wait` variable is defined, you can reuse it as much as you need to.